# Color matching between Google Earth and Google Maps (same KML)

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, google-maps-api

I'm working on a custom Google Map using API v3. I'm creating my KML files in Google Earth, uploading to Maps and then accessing the KML from there. I'm having problems matching polygon colours to the defaults in Maps - everything looks fine in Earth, but when viewing it on google maps, the colours have shifted.

**How the KML looks on Google Earth:**

[image]

**How the KML looks on Google Maps:**

[image]

You can download the KML [here](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://abiotix.com/dontdelete/run.kml).
[KML file](http://abiotix.com/dontdelete/run.kml).

Is anyone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the KML structure. Google Earth more flexible with the KML structure when Google Maps doesn't.

All the "Style" tags should be inside the "Document" tag and outside the "Folder" tag.

Here's a short KML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
      <name>orginal.kml</name>
         <Style id="1">
            <LineStyle>
               <color>ffff0000</color>
               <width>0</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
               <color>9955aaff</color>
               <fill>1</fill>
            </PolyStyle>
         </Style>
      <Folder>
         <name>pol_2013_M09_D10_0200_UTC_0200__L00_SO2_1HR_CONC</name>
         <Placemark>
            <name>17.5 - 35.0</name>
            <styleUrl>#1</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
               <SchemaData schemaUrl="#pol_2013_M09_D10_0200_UTC_0200__L00_SO2_1HR_CONC">
                  <SimpleData name="index">0</SimpleData>
                  <SimpleData name="COOD">17.5</SimpleData>
                  <SimpleData name="COOD_max">35</SimpleData>
                  <SimpleData name="VALUE">17.5 - 35.0</SimpleData>
               </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <MultiGeometry>
               <Polygon>
                  <outerBoundaryIs>
                     <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>35.09391961043328,32.69851291029587,0 35.09384988444287,32.69862535127403,0</coordinates>
                     </LinearRing>
                  </outerBoundaryIs>
               </Polygon>
            </MultiGeometry>
         </Placemark>
         <Schema id="pol_2013_M09_D10_0200_UTC_0200__L00_SO2_1HR_CONC" name="pol_2013_M09_D10_0200_UTC_0200__L00_SO2_1HR_CONC">
            <SimpleField name="Name" type="string" />
            <SimpleField name="Description" type="string" />
            <SimpleField name="index" type="int" />
            <SimpleField name="COOD" type="float" />
            <SimpleField name="COOD_max" type="float" />
            <SimpleField name="VALUE" type="string" />
         </Schema>
      </Folder>
   </Document>
</kml>
```